# Can I set the limit on how many time the Repeat Section can be repeated?

Tags: cognito-forms

In Cognito Forms, I would like to set a high limit on the repeat section. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of items in a [repeating section](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/164/account--organizations/user-management/user-permission-levels) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

[image]

You can specify a lower and upper limit, including support for calculations.